# Problema transformada de Fourier

Tags: python, numpy

Estou tendo um problema ao utilizar a função fft do numpy.
Ao rodá-la, a resposta está dando diferente da transformada de Fourier que eu implementei manualmente e pelos testes que eu fiz a manual parece correta. Acho que estou utilizando a fft de maneira errada.

```
import numpy as np
import math as m

def transformada_direta(F,x,N):
    c=[]
    for k in range (N):
        c.append(0)
    for k in range (N):
        soma=0
        for j in range (N):
            soma=soma+(F[j]*(np.exp((0-1j)*k*x[j])))
        c[k]=soma/(N)
    return c
def main():
    N=4
    T=(2*(np.pi))/N
    x=np.linspace(0.0,T*(N-1),N)
    F=[]
    for j in range (N):
        F.append(0)
    F[0]=5
    F[1]=-1
    F[2]=3
    F[3]=1
    c=transformada_direta(F,x,N)
    print(c)
    yf=np.fft.fft(F)
    print(yf)
main()
```

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas na função `transformada_direta()`, a somatória dividida por `N` não é a transformação [**inversa**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Completeness)? Não deveria ser apenas `c[k]=soma`? (ao invés de `c[k]=soma/(N)`)

Comment: Não é `x=np.linspace(0.0,T*(N-1),N)` que deveria ser `x=np.linspace(0.0, T*N, N)`? Da forma anterior, cada intervalo de `x` será de 2/3 de pi, enquanto que na sugerida seria 1/2 de pi.

Answer (score 1):

Sua FFT está diferente da da Wikipedia, veja clicando [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm#C++_Example_Code).

Abaixo, reescrevi o algoritmo em C++, na wiki acima, para Python. Faça uma comparação.

Sua amostra está muito pequena, por isso que não está conseguindo verificar corretamente o funcionamento do seu código. Quanto maior a amostra, mais fiel e menos inexata será a resposta da FFT.

Veja que, por teorema de Nyquist, a FFT só vai ter resposta válida para frequências abaixo dos 32 Hz, no exemplo abaixo. Por isso, valores acima de 32 Hz devem ser desconsiderados.

```
import numpy
import math

def separate(X):
    return X[::2] + X[1::2]

def fft(F):
    N = len(F)

    if N >= 2:
        S = separate(F)
        FirstHalf = fft(S[:N/2])
        SecondHalf = fft(S[N/2:])
        S = FirstHalf + SecondHalf
        for i in range(N/2):
            e = S[i]
            o = S[N/2+i]
            w = numpy.exp((0-2j)*numpy.pi*i)
            S[i] = e+ o*w
            S[N/2+i] = e- o*w
        return S
    else:
        return F

nsamples = 64
timespan = 1.0
samplerate = nsamples / timespan
freqresolution = samplerate / nsamples
freqs = [2,5,11,17,29]
X = [ sum(map(lambda f : math.sin(2*numpy.pi*t/nsamples*f), freqs)) 
      for t in range(nsamples) ]
F = fft(X)
maxF = max(map(lambda f: numpy.abs(f), F))

print("Smp\t  Measured\t       FFT\t Histogram\tFRs")
for i in range(nsamples):
    print("{0:3d}\t{1:10.2f}\t{2:10.2f}\t{3:10}\t{4:3.0f}"
        .format(i, X[i], numpy.abs(F[i]), '*'*(int(numpy.abs(F[i])/maxF*10.0)), i*freqresolution))
```